# get pixel coordination by rgb values matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, rgb, pixel

how can I get the x,y coordinates for pixels in an image by rgb values in matlab ?

for example : I've got an image  that I want to locate the pixels coordinates od the black area in it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find all coordinates of pixles with values `(R, G, B)` then

```
[y, x] = find(img(:,:,1)==R & img(:,:,2)==G & img(:,:,3)==B);
```

For black pixels choose `R=0, G=0, B=0`

Comment: it gives me an error "Undefined function or variable 'y'."

Comment: I use impixel to get a real rgb value in the image 
impixel gives me (11,11,11) as value for the pixel I selected 
but when I write 
 [y, x] = find(e(:,:,1)==11 & e(:,:,2)==11 & e(:,:,3)==11);
it gives me the error :
"Index exceeds matrix dimensions."
any ideas ?

Comment: @NasserTaha what is your `e`? what is `size(e)`?

Comment: sorry 
e1 = imread('eye.jpg ');
e = rgb2gray(e1);
size(e1):
966 1428 3
size(e):
966 1428

Comment: @NasserTaha if `e` is a gray-scale version, you cannot access it's "color" information at `e(:,:,2), e(:,:,3)` - it does not exist! you can access this data for `e1` - the color version of the image.

Comment: oh...any idea how to deal with the gray-scale version ?

Comment: @NasserTaha it's simple: just ignore the 2nd and 3rd channels: `[y, x] = find(e==11);`

Comment: Thanks a lot, u really helped

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in function that does this: `impixel`.
From the official documentation:

```
Return Individual Pixel Values from Image

% read a truecolor image into the workspace
RGB = imread('myimg.png');

% determine the column c and row r indices of the pixels to extract
c = [1 12 146 410];
r = [1 104 156 129];

% return the data at the selected pixel locations
pixels = impixel(RGB,c,r)

% result
pixels = 
    62    29    64
    62    34    63
   166    54    60
    59    28    47
```

Link: https://it.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/impixel.html

[EDIT]

Ok, I misunderstood your question. So to accomplish what you are looking for just use the following code:

```
img = imread('myimg.png');

r = img(:,:,1) == uint8(0);
g = img(:,:,2) == uint8(0);
b = img(:,:,3) == uint8(255);
[rows_idx,cols_idx] = find(r & g & b);
```

The example above finds all the pure blue pixels inside the image (#0000FF) and returns their indices. You can also avoid casting values to `uint8`, it should work anyway by implicitly converting values during comparison.

Comment: what are the values you gave to c and r ?

Comment: I mean I want to get the black pixels coordination ... what should c and r be ?

Comment: I think I asked the wrong way or something, I want the opposite ..
I want to get the x,y of the pixels witch have the rgb values of (0,0,0)
not the other way around...
thanks for helping

Comment: Well right now you know the tools. imread returns an m by n by 3 matrix of RGB values, one for each pixel of the image... so all you have to do is to search inside the RGB matrix. For example: find(RGB(:,:,1)==0 & RGB(:,:,2)==0 & RGB(:,:,3)==255), will return the indices of all the pure blue (#0000FF) pixels of the image. Answer edited.